# Как перехватить данные с формы и отправка API запросами с помощью JS на другой сервис?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, api

Мой вопрос о: Есть проект реализованный на ларе и с форм отправляются данные на почты с помощью PHP файла функцией Mail(), а заказчик поставил задачу, чтобы данные еще передавались на comagic. Получается надо создать событие на нажатие кнопки и до работы php файла сначала собрать данные в js script, находящемся перед , и отправить API запросом ajax'ом(?) на comagic.ru. Насколько я понимаю, код должен быть небольшой, но у меня вообще не работает. Друзья, можете накидать макет или примерный код, который будет, а то дока прочитана до дыр. Не кидайтесь, пожалста, камнями. Заранее чрезвычайно благодарен

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var __cs = __cs || [];
    __cs.push(["setCsAccount", "токен"]);
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" async src="https://app.comagic.ru/static/cs.min.js"></script>
```

вот пока накидал

Comment: Где вопрос в вашем вопросе? Что не можете сделать?

Comment: не знаешь как сделать через js
отправь curl'ом что требуется до функции mail